# can we reinitialize grid size and block size in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I was trying to write my kernel in loop.
Every time I want to change my grid size and block size..
I've written something like this..

```
dim3 grid(1,1);
dim3 block(N,N);
kernel<<<grid, block>>>();
while(condition)
{
 //Here I want to change my grid and block size
  kernel<<<grid,block>>>();
}
```

I can't use grid and block again to initialize with different value of N.
It shows error:

```
error: "grid" has already been declared in the current scope
error: "block" has already been declared in the current scope
```

so...Can anyone help me...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd get the same error message with any variable that you try to re-declare.

If you had an `int` variable, you wouldn't do this:

```
int a = 7;
int a = 5;
```

You'd do this:

```
int a = 7;
a = 5;
```

You do the same with `block` and `grid`, except that each one has up to three components:

```
dim3 grid(1,1);
dim3 block(N,N);
kernel<<<grid, block>>>();
while(condition)
{
  grid.x = 2;  grid.y = 2;
  block.x = N/2; block.y = N/2;
  kernel<<<grid,block>>>();
}
```

`dim3` is the variable type.  `block` and `grid` are just arbitrary names, you could call them anything, like this:

```
dim3 foo;
dim3 bar;
foo.x = 5; foo.y = 10;
bar.x = 2; bar.y = 4;
kernel<<<bar, foo>>>();
```